# How do I ask a user for a input file name, and then use that file name?

Tags: java, file, user-input

I am trying to ask the user for the name of their file, then I am going to scan the file to see how many indices are in the file, and then put it in an array and go from there.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;        
import java.io.*;

public class TestScoresAndSummaryStatistics {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int scores;
        int indices = -1;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the name of the file");
        String fileName = keyboard.next();

        //I believe something is wrong here, am I incorrectly bring inputFile into new File?
        File inputFile = new File(fileName);
        Scanner data = new Scanner(inputFile);

        while (data.hasNext()) {
            indices++;
        }
        System.out.println("There are: " + indices + "indices.");
    }
}
```

I believe something went wrong with the `= new File(filename);` part: maybe because I didn't have quotes, but I'm not exactly sure. How can I fix this?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Your mistake is probably the `keyboard.next()` call; try changing it to `keyboard.nextLine();`.

Comment: I dont understand the c++ part, what was that?

Comment: I dont get an error, it just never stops loading. Same with keyboard.nextLine()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

Change

```
while (data.hasNext()) {
    indices++;
}
```

to

```
while (data.hasNext()) {
    indices++;
    data.next();
}
```

## Explanation:

You want to increment `indices` for every line. To achieve this, you should go to the next line and check if there are other available lines. **Q:** How can you go to the next line ? **A:** `data.next();`

E.g. - file.txt:

**Your approach - bad**:

- Step 1

  ```
  line a    <--- here you are
  line b
  line c
  ```
- Step 2

  ```
  line a    <--- here you are
  line b
  line c
  ```

...

`data.hasNext()` will be true forever because you will be on the first line at every step => infinite loop

**Correct approach:**

- Step 1

  ```
  line a    <--- here you are
  line b
  line c
  ```
- Step 2

  ```
  line a
  line b    <--- here you are
  line c
  ```
- Step 3

  ```
  line a
  line b
  line c    <--- here you are
  ```

In this case `data.hasNext()` will return `true` only 3 times, then it will return `false` ( the file doesn't have any line after the 3rd line )

Comment: I kept the int indices = -1 because I did not want to include the first number in the file, since that is suppose to represent how many numbers are in the file. Though I did add data.next(); and it worked, would you mind telling why that worked, I would just like to understand a bit more if you dont mind.

Comment: I suggested to use indices = 0 because I supposed that you try to count indices and 0 is also countable. Ok, I will edit the post to add some details.

Answer (score 0):

You only check if there is data in `Scanner` but you never consume it.

> The java.util.Scanner.hasNext() method Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to scan. The scanner does not advance past any input.

The below code will never end if there is any data in file, you increase your counter with out reading the data.

```
   while (data.hasNext()) {
        indices++;
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what your getting at, how would I "consume" it? Aren't I already storing it into variable data?

Comment: I don't know how to put it any simpler. You check if there is data to read and you never read it. Where do you think you store it?

Comment: So your talking about my while loop needs some changing?

Comment: Yea I included the part of code to point the problem. You need to read something ... What are you counting otherwise?